# Server failed to authenticate the request - Azure Queue Storage REST API (PUT Method)

Tags: azure, postman, azure-storage, azure-queues, azure-rest-api

Following this TechCommunity [MS Article](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-paas-blog/azure-storage-how-to-migrate-azure-queue-data-from-one-account/bc-p/4076711#M667) for Storage Queue Data Migration:

From that article, 1st REST API of Listing Queues on Source Storage account is working perfectly.

Now, working on the 2nd REST API marked with the statement:

> Create queues with the same names in the Target storage account.

**Context**: ***This REST API puts the source storage queues to the destination storage account.***

I do not know where to get the values for these headers: `x-ms-request-id`, `x-ms-version` and `Date` to pass in the Post Method REST API.

I only know the value of below headers:

`Server`: `Windows-Azure-Queue/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0`

[image]

**My Rest API**: `https://deststore121.queue.core.windows.net/azure-webjobs-blobtrigger-csstechwebapp?<SOURCE_STORAGE_SAS_TOKEN>`

**Error**:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
    <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
Time:2024-03-06T06:11:20.2934664Z</Message>
```

Comment: Whether the first step is worked for you?

Comment: Yep, 1st rest api is working successfully.

Comment: You need to create a sas token from target storage account. then try the above request.

Comment: Tried with that also.. didn't get and if you see the article, there is a change in storage account name only not in sas token for the 2nd rest API because that source storage sas token contains the queue data I believe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Create queues with the same names in the Target storage account.

I followed the same document you shared in my environment.

**First step:**

To list the queues, use the source storage account URL with the source SAS token.

**Postman:**

[image]

Now, to create the same queue in a different storage or destination storage account, you need to create a SAS token in the destination storage account.

In my environment, I created a SAS token from the destination storage account through the portal.

**Second step:**

To create a new queue in the destination storage account follow below request.

**Postman:**

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

**Reference:**

[Create Queue (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-queue4)

Comment: Oh, do we need to specify the queue name in the REST API URL? If we have multiple queues, do we have to run this API multiple times by changing the queue names?

Comment: Yes, By changing names it will create new queues.

Comment: Thank you, @Venkateshan, for your prompt response. Your professionalism is acknowledged and valued.